# Restart a quiz after displaying the score

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this code on my website to create a quiz. It works perfectly except that I need to a add a button that can restart the quiz from scratch once the score is displayed.

The player will answer all questions until they finish the quiz. Once the score is displayed a button to restart is shown. Thanks

The code:
Html:

```
<!-- Main page -->
<div class="main">
    <!-- Number of Question  -->
    <div class="wrapper" id="pages">
        <span id="quizNumber">1</span><span>/7</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Quiz Question -->
    <div class="quiz-questions" id="display-area">
        <p id="question"></p>
        <ul id="answer">
        </ul>

        <div id="quiz-results">
            <button type="button" name="button" class="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
   // Creating questionss and answers
//*****************************************************************************
var question1 = {
    question: "What does HTML stand for?",
    answers: ["Hyper Text Markup Language", "HyperLinks and Text Markup Language", "Home Tool Markup Language"],
    correct: 0
};

var question2 = {
    question: "The Bootstrap grid system is based on how many columns?",
    answers: ['6', '9', '12', '3'],
    correct: 2
};


// create an array of objects

var questions = [question1, question2];

// Initialize variables
//------------------------------------------------------------------

var tags;
var tagsClass = '';
var liTagsid = [];
var correctAns = 0;
var quizPage = 1;


var currentIndex = 0;
var currentQuestion = questions[currentIndex];

var prevousQuestion;
var previousIndex = 0;

var ulTag = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var button = document.getElementById('submit');
var questionTitle = document.getElementById('question');

//save class name so it can be reused easily
//if I want to change it, I have to change it one place
var classHighlight = 'selected';


// Display Answers and hightlight selected item
//------------------------------------------------------------------
function showQuestions() {

    if (currentIndex != 0) {
        // create again submit button only for next pages
        ulTag.innerHTML = '';
        button.innerHTML = 'Submit';
        button.className = 'submit';
        button.id = 'submit';

        //update the number of questions displayed
        document.getElementById('quizNumber').innerHTML = quizPage;
    }

    //Display Results in the final page
    if (currentIndex == (questions.length)) {
        ulTag.innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = '';

        showResults();

        return
    }

    questionTitle.innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;
    console.log(currentQuestion.question);

    // create a for loop to generate the answers and display them in the page
    for (var i = 0; i < currentQuestion.answers.length; i++) {
        // creating answers
        var newAns = document.createElement('li');
        newAns.id = 'ans' + (i + 1);
        newAns.className = "notSelected";
        var textAns = document.createTextNode(currentQuestion.answers[i]);
        newAns.appendChild(textAns);
        var addNewAnsHere = document.getElementById('answer');
        addNewAnsHere.appendChild(newAns);

        console.log(currentQuestion.answers[i]);
    }


    //.click() will return the result of $('.notSelected')
    var $liTags = $('.notSelected').click(function(list) {
        list.preventDefault();
        //run removeClass on every element
        //if the elements are not static, you might want to rerun $('.notSelected')
        //instead of the saved $litTags
        $liTags.removeClass(classHighlight);
        //add the class to the currently clicked element (this)
        $(this).addClass(classHighlight);

        //get id name of clicked answer
        for (var i = 0; i < currentQuestion.answers.length; i++) {
            // console.log(liTagsid[i]);
            if ($liTags[i].className == "notSelected selected") {
                //store information to check answer
                tags = $liTags[i].id;
                // tagsClass = $LiTags.className;
                console.log(tags);
                tagsClassName = $liTags[i];
            }
        }
    });

    //check answer once it has been submitted
    button.onclick = function() {
        checkAnswer()
    };
}

//self calling function
showQuestions();


// Show Correct Answer
//------------------------------------------------------------------
function checkAnswer() {
    // get selected list
    var selectedItem = document.getElementById(tags);

    // check that an answer has been selected
    if (selectedItem == undefined) {
        alert("Please selected an answer!")
        return
    } else {
        // get user answer if form of text
        var userAns = selectedItem.innerHTML;
    }

    // change the background of the answer according to the Results
    if (userAns == currentQuestion.answers[currentQuestion.correct]) {
        console.log("Correct! The answer is: " + userAns);
        // change color of selected item by changing className
        selectedItem.className = 'correct';
        // count the number of correct answers
        correctAns++;
        console.log(correctAns);
    } else {
        console.log("Wrong! The corrent answer is: " + currentQuestion.answers[currentQuestion.correct]);
        //change the background of the wrong answer
        selectedItem.className = 'wrong';
        //hightlight the right answer if the user got it wrong
        //change the class name of the correct answer
        ulTag.getElementsByTagName('li')[currentQuestion.correct].className = 'correct';

        console.log(currentQuestion.answers[currentQuestion.correct]);
    }

    // Create a next Question button once the answer has been submitted
    button.innerHTML = 'Next Question';
    button.className = 'next';
    button.id = 'next';

    prevousQuestion = currentQuestion;
    quizPage++;
    currentIndex++;
    currentQuestion = questions[currentIndex];

    // Start with the next question once the "Next" button has been clicked
    button.onclick = function() {
        showQuestions()
    };
    return
}

// Final score
//------------------------------------------------------------------
function showResults() {
    //deleting page number
    document.getElementById('pages').innerHTML = '';

    // Change Title
    questionTitle.innerHTML = '<h1>Your Score</h1>';

    // Get the area that will be used to display the user's score
    var newInfo = document.getElementById('quiz-results');
    //Change the id and className of the area for the circle
    newInfo.innerHTML = '';
    newInfo.id = 'circle';
    newInfo.className = 'circle';


    //Create a Div for the fill element
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.className = 'fill';
    var addHere = document.getElementById('circle');
    addHere.appendChild(newDiv);

    // add the score to the circle
    var newScore = document.createElement('h3');
    newScore.className = 'score';
    var textScore = document.createTextNode(Math.floor((correctAns / questions.length) * 100) + '%');
    newScore.appendChild(textScore);
    addHere.appendChild(newScore);

    //use jquery to grab the text of the score
    var score = $(".score").text();

    //fill the circle in base of the score
    $(".fill").css("height", score);

    if (correctAns >= 5) {
        var newCongrats = document.createElement('p');
        var textCongrats = document.createTextNode('Congratulations! You did a Good Job!')
        newCongrats.appendChild(textCongrats);
        document.getElementById('display-area').appendChild(newCongrats);

        confettiEffect();
    }

}

// Confetti Effect by Gtibo "Confetti Party"
//------------------------------------------------------------------
function confettiEffect() {
    //grabing area to create the effect
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    // creating the tabel
    particle = [];
    particleCount = 0,
        gravity = 0.3,
        colors = [
            '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
            '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
            '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
            '#FF5722', '#795548'
        ];

    for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {

        particle.push({
            x: width / 2,
            y: height / 2,
            boxW: randomRange(5, 20),
            boxH: randomRange(5, 20),
            size: randomRange(2, 8),

            spikeran: randomRange(3, 5),

            velX: randomRange(-8, 8),
            velY: randomRange(-50, -10),

            angle: convertToRadians(randomRange(0, 360)),
            color: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
            anglespin: randomRange(-0.2, 0.2),

            draw: function() {
                context.save();
                context.translate(this.x, this.y);
                context.rotate(this.angle);
                context.fillStyle = this.color;
                context.beginPath();

                context.fillRect(this.boxW / 2 * -1, this.boxH / 2 * -1, this.boxW, this.boxH);
                context.fill();
                context.closePath();
                context.restore();
                this.angle += this.anglespin;
                this.velY *= 0.999;
                this.velY += 0.3;

                this.x += this.velX;
                this.y += this.velY;

                if (this.y < 0) {
                    this.velY *= -0.2;
                    this.velX *= 0.9;
                };

                if (this.y > height) {
                    this.anglespin = 0;
                    this.y = height;
                    this.velY *= -0.2;
                    this.velX *= 0.9;
                };

                if (this.x > width || this.x < 0) {
                    this.velX *= -0.5;
                };
            },
        });
    }

    function drawScreen() {
        context.globalAlpha = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < particle.length; i++) {
            particle[i].draw();
        }
    }

    function loadImage(url) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = url;
        return img;
    }

    function update() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        drawScreen();
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }

    update();

    function randomRange(min, max) {
        return min + Math.random() * (max - min);
    }

    function randomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
    }

    function convertToRadians(degree) {
        return degree * (Math.PI / 180);
    }

    function drawStar(cx, cy, spikes, outerRadius, innerRadius, color) {
        var rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3;
        var x = cx;
        var y = cy;
        var step = Math.PI / spikes;

        context.strokeSyle = "#000";
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(cx, cy - outerRadius)
        for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
            x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;
            y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius;
            context.lineTo(x, y)
            rot += step

            x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
            y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
            context.lineTo(x, y)
            rot += step
        }

        context.lineTo(cx, cy - outerRadius)
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.fill();

    }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried and what went wrong?

Comment: I tried to implement function showQuestions()  after showing results but didn't work.

Comment: Calling `showQuestions()` again will fail because you clear `#pages` with `document.getElementById('pages').innerHTML = '';`.
`#pages` contains `#quiz-number` which is needed in `showQuestions()` so it will fail on `document.getElementById('quizNumber').innerHTML = quizPage;`

Comment: You would need to re-create this page. Or you could just hide `#pages` with css `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

It works using this code:

```
var fullReset = document.getElementById('fullReset');

fullReset.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  location.reload();
}, false);
```

However, I wish to hide that button and display it just after showing the score.